# How to provide password / security for a directory even root also want to access?

Tags: permissions, password, security, ecryptfs, truecrypt

In My ubuntu, there are some confidential certificates in one directory. my colleagues know my root password and user password. Now i want to restrict to access that folder with password / security other than root password. I don't want to use any GUI based 3rd party applications. I want to DO it only through commands.

and one more is i tried ecryptfs. It is working fine. But i'm unable to access the files in protected directory through my C application. Help me how to access ecryptfs protected directory from c application.

Please suggest me some standard way to restrict.

Comment: Look at [Ravexina's Answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/932194/423684) to a similar question. There is NO real way to stop a root user..

Comment: for atleast one directory also not possible ? or any other way to restrict root user with password / security from usage of users directory ?

Comment: if you read the mentioned answer there is already explained why this is not possible. The root user is the master of the whole system. There are ways like encryption e.g. to at least make it more difficult but the root user can do anything so he can easely give himself the permissions he wants

Comment: ok thank you. But for every problem their is a solution. I'm asking is there any solution for that ? Just now i seen FUSE file system, is it helps for me ? i don't know about FUSE FS.